# Custom Button Issue

Tags: custom-button, case, contact, url, custom-url

Is this correct way ?

**I am trying to "View all cases which are related to the Contact I have on my current Case"

(Sibling Cases - Case records who shares same Contact as parent/lookup).**

Example :

I am on detail page of

Case1 ---where Contact = Con1

Con1 --- has Case5,Case6,Case7,Case1 on it.

when I click "Custom_Button" it should show me all the Case records related to "Con1"  i.e. Case5,Case6,Case7,Case1

**STEPS :** 
Case Record Details Page 
-> Related_List  "Related Cases"
-> Here I have one Custom_Button where

> Button or Link URL = `/500?id={!Contact.Id}`

From sources I got this :

- The internal server error message is occurring because the button is trying to override(/500?id={!Contact.Id}) the URL to bring the page to a list view that has an ID of a contact record, which cannot be done.
- It works fine when an actual list view ID is referenced but will fail when the ID is a contact ID

> Example: `https://yp.my.salesforce.com/500?id=00B40000006c8YG`

Any Ideas how can I achive this one ? Any Suggestions ?

Comment: you can easily achieve this on custom page or do you want to acheive this on standard list view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please change the URL to:

```
/500?rlid=RelatedCaseList&id={!Case.ContactId}
```

And keep the button behaviour as `Display in existing window without sidebar or header`

Please let me know if it works.

Thanks!

Comment: Great ! it works. @Shailesh Can you provide some Doc/link explaining this ! 

I mean to understand WHY  in detail?